# Filter by two items react-instantsearch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-instantsearch

I am sure this is probably a beginner issue but, I am trying to filter by both `ongoing` and `all_day`. How can this be achieved in the same `.filter()`?

```
<CurrentRefinements
  transformItems={items =>
    items.filter(item => item.attribute !== 'ongoing', 'all_day')
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include more than one condition, add it using `&&` or `||`:

```
items.filter(item => item.attribute !== 'ongoing' && item.attribute !== 'all_day')
```